# Is there a way to specify the directory to which a serialised list (in the form of an XML File) is saved

Tags: xml, vb.net, winforms, file, serialization

I am using a sub to serialize and save a number of lists within my program. By default, the XML files are found in the "Debug" folder. For organisational reasons, I would like to specify a directory path for my files to follow.

The following is my sub:

```
    Public Sub XMLSave(ByVal listName As IEnumerable(Of Object), ByVal fileName As String)

    fileName = (fileName & ".xml")

    Dim save As New XmlSerializer(listName.GetType)

    Using Writer As New IO.StreamWriter(fileName)

        save.Serialize(Writer, listName)

    End Using

End Sub
```

Comment: So, create a Directory (`Dim dirInfo = Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "MyDir"));`), then combine the new Directory path with the file name: `Dim fileName = Path.Combine(dirInfo.Name, "MyFile.txt")`. The point is, how do you plan to decide when a File needs to be stored in a specific Directory? You'll need to add some logic to the simple file creation thing.

Comment: Just put it in the StreamWriter... IO.StreamWriter(Path.Combine("c:\Somefolder\", fileName))